# Converting rows in Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am developing an asp.net mvc application with NHibernate and I have a query where I would like to know how can I convert rows in columns?

I have a dynamic system with a model like this:

```
// It's a kind of metadata
public class Field
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

// the value is here with respective field
public class FieldValue
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
   public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know how can I get a result where columns are the Field objects and values are FieldValue objects, should I create a ViewModel?  or a way to do it with asp.net mvc?

I can do a query to get a result like this:

[image]

But I would like to do a query like this (or a way to create a result on my View on the asp.net mvc):

[image]

Thanks

Comment: "columns are the Field objects and values are FieldValue objects" Still not clear what this means

Comment: Do you mean *pivot* your result set returned from the query?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry, take a look at my edits, I add some imagens to illustrate better! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to need to get fancy/familiar with GroupBy().  If you Group By the Field, you "group" all the values for a field then move to the next one.  The pseudo-code would be something like the following

```
@model IEnumerable<FieldValue>

foreach(var fields in Model.GroupBy(x=>x.Field.Name){
    <h2>fields.key</h2>
    <ul>
        foreach(var fieldValue in fields){
             <li>@fieldValue.Value</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

This should render something like

**Field 1**

- some value 1
- some value 2

**Field 2**

- some value 3
- some value 4

etc.

By using this approach, you can control the formatting however you want to get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you @Tommy, I will try this later and back to check your awser. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with the question. if you want to transform rows into columns - you can use pivot. But i would suggest instead of operating on resultset to transpose, let it return the transposed result set. I meant handle the conversion of rows into columns in your query itself

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if it's possible but take a look at my edits, I add some images.